# How do I make my code faster?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

The following code works great to accomplish what I want to achieve in netsuite, but I am having trouble finding ways to make it faster.  I tried not using the system nlapi as frequently, but I couldn't seem to make it work without submitting the record.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
function WonLost(type, name) {
    if (name == 'custbody138') {
        var recordid = nlapiGetRecordId();
        var record = nlapiLoadRecord('estimate', recordid);
        if ((nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody138')) == 'T') {
            var itemsall = "";
            var lineCount = parseInt(record.getLineItemCount('item'));
            var x = 1;
            while (x <= lineCount) {
                nlapiSelectLineItem('item', x);
                nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol55', 'T', 'false');
                nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
                x++;
            }
        }

        else {
            var itemsall = "";
            var lineCount = parseInt(record.getLineItemCount('item'));
            var x = 1;
            while (x <= lineCount) {
                nlapiSelectLineItem('item', x);
                nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol55', 'F', 'false');
                nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want to read it faster you have to indent it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek [Vote to close because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, not because it belongs somewhere else](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286591/1310566). Voting to close because it belongs somewhere else can cause situations where the question is closed on two places. It is okay to redirect people to other sites, but don't vote to close with that reason. Vote to close as "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" instead.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg There is a reason why there is a option listed *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* on the off-topic section. If the site is not included in the list you use a custom flag for migration.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, you use a *custom flag* for migration. Not a *close vote* for migration.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Oh your right, I didn't noticed I clicked the *close* button. I thought I clicked *flag* :P (the starting text was there by default). Alright I flagged it and removed my close-vote.

Comment: always amazed to see people commenting this or that about a close vote or flag from a fellow user when the brand new O.P. just shown plain disrespect for S.O. rules... :-)

Comment: I didn't realize that codereview.stackexchange.com was an option until this conversation.  Yes I did read the FAQ when I signed up, just missed it as a site when I looked at the site list.  Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of script is this in?

It looks like you are loading the record that the script is deployed on. This is completely unnecessary, and you can just use `nlapi*` functions instead of `record.*` functions. Loading an entire record is one of the more expensive operations you can do.

- Delete your `recordid` and `record` variables
- Replace your `record.getLineItemCount` calls with `nlapiGetLineItemCount`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is on Recalc Function of a client script and set the `'custcol55'` to 'T' so you don't need to iterate the whole item list.

Answer (score -3):

There is this concept of **overhead** that I slept through in college, but my basic understanding is that looping can be expensive. (performance intensive)

So if there are 100 lines and you loop through them 1 at a time, that's 100 loops, but if you can handle 5 lines per loop then it's only 20 loops.  It's called "loop unrolling", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

So don't do this...

```
while (x<= lineCount)
{
//do stuff on line x
x++;
}
```

Instead try this...

```
while (x<= lineCount)
{
//do stuff on line x
//do stuff on line x+1
//do stuff on line x+2
//do stuff on line x+3
//do stuff on line x+4
x=x+5;
}
```

And you also have to handle situations where there are 47 lines, so you only loop up to ((int)(linecount/5)*5) and then do a mini 1-at-a-time loop at the end to handle 46 and 47 (linecount%5).

This results in really ugly, not elegant code, but I've seen it be very helpful for performance, specifically in chunking long sql queries.  You have to play around with the chunk size, 5 might be too small or too large to have a benefit, so adjust it and log your times until you find the sweet spot.

Comment: haha.  Maybe while I'm back in college I'll meet the person who created the stackoverflow policy that requires me to build my reputation by giving poor answers to questions before I'm allowed to comment.